# Subquery with alias in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I have a query that I run in PostgreSQL like this:

```
select
    c_count, count(*) as custdist
from (
    select
       c_custkey,
       count(o_orderkey)
     from
       customer left outer join orders on
       c_custkey = o_custkey
       and o_comment not like '%special%requests%'
      group by
        c_custkey
      )as c_orders (c_custkey, c_count)
group by
     c_count
order by
     custdist desc,
     c_count desc;
```

And I wanted to run it on SQLite, but I got this error: `Error: near" (": syntax error`. Maybe he doesn't recognize this `as c_orders (c_custkey, c_count)`.
Is there any way to rewrite this query to execute in SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQLite does not allow redefining/renaming columns for an nested, aliased query. You can do that with a [WITH clause](https://www.sqlite.org/draft/lang_with.html) (i.e. Common Table Expression; CTE). Or you can add aliases to the nested query columns directly using AS keyword.

Interesting that this is exactly how the outer query columns are named.  Just use the same pattern for the nested query.  I don't use PostgreSQL, but why not add aliases directly on each column and complicate it by using different syntax for each part of the query?

```
select
    c_count, count(*) as custdist
from (
    select
       c_custkey,
       count(o_orderkey) AS c_count
     from
       customer left outer join orders on
       c_custkey = o_custkey
       and o_comment not like '%special%requests%'
      group by
        c_custkey
      ) AS c_orders 
group by
     c_count
order by
     custdist desc,
     c_count desc;
```